# Changing routes to index path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `/users/1/settings` and `/profile/1/settings`. How can I modify routes so that it would be simpler such as `/settings`?

routes.rb:

```
 get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  get 'edit' => 'users#edit'
  get "/profile/:id" => "users#show"
  get "profile/:id/settings" => 'users#edit'
  get 'settings/:id' => 'users#settings'

  resources :users do  
    get 'settings', on: :member  
    post 'follow', on: :member 
    post 'unfollow', on: :member
    get "follow", on: :member 
  end
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

according to railscasts

```
  resourses: users, :has_many => :settings, :shallow => true
```

will help you

Watch [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources) from **6:30**